# Layouting a row of bricks on the wall in XNA 4

Tags: xna-4.0, bounding-box

I am very new to XNA 3D programing, and my English is not very good!

**My problem:**

I have two 3D box model (that I created in 3Ds max), the bigger one for the wall and the smaller for the brick, I want to layout a row of bricks on my wall but I don't know how can I get the wall and bricks "corners" , "perfect BoundingBox" and the front side of them.

For getting bounding box i used the code from [this tutorial](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/XNA/html/xna_bounding_box.html), but this doesn't work well and calling `BoundingBox.GetCorners()` method doesn't give me the correct corners of my boxes.

**How do I get the bounding box reliably?**

Comment: You might want to add why "this doesn't work well". Does it give a run-time error?  Are the numbers you get not what you expect?  More detail will help get you an answer.